# can the different hosts (not ip) forwarding to the same port externally?

Tags: sockets, tcp, communication, portforwarding

Im just wondering, can 2 or more different external hostname/DNS redirect to multiple local servers but same port?

Let's see, I have 2 DNS internet domain for an example, myserver1.com and myserver2.com, and both I have same A record to my forwarded server IP (e.g: 102.123.123.123). Under my server which only has 102.123.123.123 IP address has 2 application servers but instead of trying to make they work, I use different port for each server applications for an example, serverApp1 listening to 0.0.0.0:2010, serverApp2 listening to 0.0.0.0:2020

My point is, is there any way or how to forward my myserver1.com:2000 to serverApp1 (port 2010), and myserver2.com:2000 to serverApp2 (port 2020) but both myserver1.com and myserver2.com has a same A record?

Im quite sure either it is in iptables or /etc/hosts or BIND issues, but guide me if I missed something. And by the way, the servers and DNS records are accessible from the internet which is the firewalls are configured properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in that, but I think you will need a third server/firewall/proxy listening for the incoming host and route it accordingly.

Again, I don't have much experience in that, so I'm not sure if the firewall is able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use redirection servers like apache.

In my application we want to access lot of intranet servers from internet. So what we did, we configured a apache with all the mappings in httpd.

So when ever a request to apache comes, it will be redirected appropriately.

For example - I have two servers or hostname in intranet : 1) abc.com:7300/context1
2) xyz.com:8900/context2

We configured a apache with host name abcxyz.com:9000. When a request like 
abcxyz.com:9000/context1 comes it will be redirected to abc.com:7300/context1 and when a request like abcxyz.com:9000/context2 comes it will be redirected to xyz.com:8900/context2.

In your case since the requests are going through the single server (102.123.123.123), you can use redirection.

Hope it helps.